# Automapper with Entity Framework, Initialization Error

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have an EF6 MVC app using Code First to generate the models.  I am trying to create a mapping using AutoMapper between the model and a view model representation of that model.  However, when I do the mapping I receive the error:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate
>   configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a
>   container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the
>   static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or
>   UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the
>   appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

I am definitely initializing the Mapper, but I am not able to figure out why the configuration is failing.  Could anyone provide some assistance on what I can do to successfully use AutoMapper in this situation?

Here is the code for how I am configuring and initializing the Mapper:

```
    var pTConnections = _db.PTConnections.Include(p => p.PTConnectionClass).ToList();

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<PTConnection, PTConnectionViewModel>()
                .AfterMap((s, d) => { foreach (var i in d.PTCredentialAssignments) i.PTConnection = d; });

            cfg.CreateMap<PTCredentialAssignment, PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTCredential, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnection, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<PTVendor, PTVendorViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTCredentials, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnections, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<PTCredential, PTCredentialViewModel>();

            cfg.CreateMap<PTConnectionClass, PTConnectionClassViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnections, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<PTConnectionContactAssignment, PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnection, opt => opt.Ignore());

        });

    var dest = Mapper.Map<List<PTConnection>, List<PTConnectionViewModel>>(pTConnections);
```

Here is my Code First Model:

```
public partial class PTConnection
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTConnection()
    {
        PTConnectionAssignments = new HashSet<PTConnectionAssignment>();
        PTCredentialAssignments = new HashSet<PTCredentialAssignment>();
        PTConnectionContactAssignments = new HashSet<PTConnectionContactAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ConnectionName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    public int Port { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int PTCCID { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public int PTVID { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnectionClass PTConnectionClass { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionAssignment> PTConnectionAssignments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignment> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

    public virtual PTVendor PTVendor { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionContactAssignment> PTConnectionContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTCredential
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTCredential()
    {
        PTCredentialAssignments = new HashSet<PTCredentialAssignment>();
        PTCredentialContactAssignments = new HashSet<PTCredentialContactAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CredUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string CredPassword { get; set; }

    public string Directory { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int? PTVID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignment> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

    public virtual PTVendor PTVendor { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialContactAssignment> PTCredentialContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTVendor
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTVendor()
    {
        PTConnections = new HashSet<PTConnection>();
        PTCredentials = new HashSet<PTCredential>();
        PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignments = new HashSet<PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignment>();
        PTVendorAssignments = new HashSet<PTVendorAssignment>();
        PTVendorContactAssignments = new HashSet<PTVendorContactAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTVID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50), Display(Name="Vendor Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnection> PTConnections { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredential> PTCredentials { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignment> PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTVendorAssignment> PTVendorAssignments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTVendorContactAssignment> PTVendorContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

[Table("PTCredentialAssignment")]
public partial class PTCredentialAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCRAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnection PTConnection { get; set; }

    public virtual PTCredential PTCredential { get; set; }
}

[Table("PTConnectionClass")]
public partial class PTConnectionClass
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTConnectionClass()
    {
        PTConnections = new HashSet<PTConnection>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTCCID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnection> PTConnections { get; set; }
}

[Table("PTConnectionContactAssignment")]
public partial class PTConnectionContactAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCCAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnection PTConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
   public partial class PTConnectionViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int PTCID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string ConnectionName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Host { get; set; }

        public int Port { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public int PTCCID { get; set; }

        public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

        public int PTVID { get; set; }

        public virtual PTConnectionClassViewModel PTConnectionClass { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionAssignmentViewModel> PTConnectionAssignments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

        public virtual PTVendorViewModel PTVendor { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel> PTConnectionContactAssignments { get; set; }
    }

public partial class PTVendorViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTVID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50), Display(Name="Vendor Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionViewModel> PTConnections { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialViewModel> PTCredentials { get; set; }

}

public partial class PTCredentialViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CredUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string CredPassword { get; set; }

    public string Directory { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int? PTVID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

    public virtual PTVendorViewModel PTVendor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialContactAssignmentViewModel> PTCredentialContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCRAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnectionViewModel PTConnection { get; set; }

    public virtual PTCredentialViewModel PTCredential { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTConnectionClassViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public int PTCCID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionViewModel> PTConnections { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCCAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnectionViewModel PTConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Amy, I made the modifications you suggested, however I get a new error now:

_"Error mapping types.
\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nList`1 -> List`1\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PTApp.Models.PTConnection, PTApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] 
-> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PTApp.ViewModels.PTConnectionViewModel, PTApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}_

Comment: That's because each property type also needs to be mapped.  It doesn't know how to map each property, for example `PTConnectionClass ` needs to be mapped to `PTConnectionClassViewModel `.  Once all the property types are mapped you can map the main objects.

Comment: Furthermore, if you expand that exception and inspect the inner exception, it will tell you which property it can't map.

Comment: @Amy, I added the mappings but now it is telling me that there is a Stack Overflow Exception.  Any thoughts on what would cause this?  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Yeah, you're now (auto)mapping objects (yay!), but you have a circular reference somewhere.  Those can be tricky.  I'd suggest googling "automapper circular reference".

Comment: **Thanks** @Amy! I was able to get around the circular references by using some ignore methods on the offending properties (post updated). I don't have errors, but the resulting object is missing details for the PTCredential object. Specifically I am missing the PTCredential object that is nested within a PTCredential. I don't believe the Ignores are causing this, but I can't pin it down.  I have tried some suggestions from other posts on AM, but nothing has proven useful. Any suggestions on how to get it included?

Comment: I'd ask a new question with your mapping code and the gist of your models.

Answer (score 5):

Just create the map from one type to another.  Don't create the map from a List of one type to a list of another type.  Automapper can automatically handle collections.

In effect, you're telling Automapper how to map a `List<A>` to a `List<B>` without telling Automapper how to actually map `A` to `B`.  Change your registration to the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<PTConnection, PTConnectionViewModel>();
});
```

You can still map a `List<PTConnection>` to a `List<PTConnectionViewModel>` just fine, as well as most other collection types.