# Mapper not initialized, When Use ProjectTo()

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap, automapper-5

I Use **Automapper 5.2.0** In My Project. When I Use `ProjectTo()` In Code Get This Error:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with Appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

**Service Code**

```
 public async Task<FreelancerProfileViewModel> GetFreelancerProfile()
    {
        var id = Guid.Parse(_identity.GetUserId());
        var model = await _freelancerProfiles
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(_ => _.User.Id == id)
            .ProjectTo<FreelancerProfileViewModel>()
            .FirstAsync();

     //  var viewmodel =  _mapper.Map<FreelancerProfileViewModel>(model);

        return model;
    }
```

**Automapper Profile**

```
   public class FreelancerDashbordProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly IIdentity _identity;
    public FreelancerDashbordProfile(IIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
        var id = Guid.Parse(_identity.GetUserId());
        CreateMap<FreelancerProfile, FreelancerProfileViewModel>()
        .ForMember(_ => _.DoingProjectCount,
            __ => __.MapFrom(_ => _.Projects.Count(project => project.ProjectState == ProjectState.Doing)))

        .ForMember(_ => _.EndProjectCount,
            __ => __.MapFrom(_ => _.Projects.Count(project => project.ProjectState == ProjectState.End)))

        .ForMember(_ => _.ProjectCount, __ => __.MapFrom(_ => _.Projects.Count));

    }

}
```

Also I Use [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/quickstart/) For [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

**AutoMapperRegistery**

```
   public AutoMapperRegistery()
    {

        this.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.AssemblyContainingType<SkillProfile>(); // for other asms, if any.
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();

            scan.AddAllTypesOf<Profile>().NameBy(item => item.FullName);
        });

        this.For<MapperConfiguration>().Singleton().Use("MapperConfig", ctx =>
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; // It will connect `Person` & `PersonViewModel` automatically.
                addAllCustomAutoMapperProfiles(ctx, cfg);
            });
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            return config;
        });

        this.For<IMapper>()
            .Singleton()
            .Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(ctx.GetInstance));


    }
```

I See Other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417633/automapper-with-entity-framework-initialization-error) and [Issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1524) but not solved my problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to pass the MappingConfiguration provider to the ProjectTo call.

```
public async Task<FreelancerProfileViewModel> GetFreelancerProfile()
{
    var id = Guid.Parse(_identity.GetUserId());
    var model = await _freelancerProfiles
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(_ => _.User.Id == id)
        .ProjectTo<FreelancerProfileViewModel>(_mapper.Configuration)
        .FirstAsync();

 //  var viewmodel =  _mapper.Map<FreelancerProfileViewModel>(model);

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to pass configuration provider to all mappings? I think this is not a good solution. Do I have to pass config file to my all queries? I didn't find any better solution by the way :/

Comment: If are you looking for unit test case as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481934/mapper-not-initialized-error-with-my-unit-test-core-net-2-0#comment82018472_47481934 in the `Mapper.Initialize` for dotnet core 2.x+ add type Startup like `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup))`

Comment: @ahmet I don't think there is a "native" way with AutoMapper, but you could write a very simple Extension Method which wraps the ProjectTo<>() call and injects the _mapper.Configuration reference every time it is called.

Answer (score 20):

In the .NET Core 3.1 (AutoMapper 9.0.0) new registration is:
`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`

In the .NET Core 2.1 (AutoMapper 7.0.1) version you have to pass the `ConfigurationProvider`.

1. Register AutoMapper like described [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core)
2. Inject to the Controller:

   private readonly IMapper  _mapper;
   public SomeController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
   { _mapper = mapper; }
3. Pass the `ConfigurationProvider` this way:

   ApplicationDbContext.SomeEntities.ProjectTo(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)

Comment: This case is about ASP.NET MVC 5.X ( full framework no .net core ). anyway, thanks to announcing.

Comment: There are no any mentions about it above. So let's leave it generic

Comment: Is there a way to wire it up in a static extension method ?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for ProjectTo, but is there a way to get Mapper.Map() to work?

Comment: `Mapper.Map` is old approach and it's obsolete. New approach - inject the `IMapper` to the target type. Not sure if they still support the first one. Try to find the docs