# use AutoMapper.EF6,but Mapper not initialized error happed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

the error info :

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate
>   configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a
>   container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the
>   static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or
>   UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the
>   appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance. InnerException: 
>   StackTrace: at AutoMapper.Mapper.get_Configuration()

**the asp.net mvc5 controller code**

```
public override ActionResult Kendo_Read(DataSourceRequest request, IQueryable<Activity> results)
{
    var data = results.ProjectTo<ActivityViewModel>();
    var rdata = data.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(rdata);
}
```

**AutoMapper Configure Code**

```
public class CRMProfile : Profile
{
  CreateMap<Activity, ActivityViewModel>();
}

public static class Configuration
{
   public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration()
   {
        return new MapperConfiguration(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile(new CRMProfile());
        }
   }
}
```

**Register Code**

```
internal static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; private set; }
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
      MapperConfiguration = Configuration.MapperConfiguration();
}
```

i home return data type is IQueryable in the controller,not List,
I See the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961439/mapper-not-initialized-when-use-projectto) and Issue in stackoverflow but could not solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AutoMapper's source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs) you can see that this exception will be thrown when configuration is not initialized at all:

```
public static IConfigurationProvider Configuration
{
    get => _configuration ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(InvalidOperationMessage);
    private set => _configuration = value;
}
```

Make sure that `Mapper` is correctly configured using static properties or correctly registered using IoC container if you are using that (please, refer to [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration) for details). Are you perhaps missing the `Mapper.Initialize()` call?