# AutoMapper mapping ICollection with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I'm trying to map nested ICollection of one of my models to existing Dto, but I'm struggling to Map it properly with AutoMapper

**Models:**

```
public class Ingredient : BaseEntity<long>
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPackaging { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductIngredient> ProductIngredient { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IngredientComposition> IngredientComposition { get; set; }
}
```

**Collection Model:**

```
public class IngredientComposition : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Dto:**

```
public class IngredientDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CretedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int UsedCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsPackaging { get; set; }
    public IList<Composition> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Composition
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

My maps looks as follows as I'm struggling to properly set "ForMemeber" method(s):

```
CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>();
CreateMap<IngredientDto, Ingredient>();
```

Any help much appropriated!
Thanks

EDIT:

This is how I'm getting data:

```
return await _context.Ingredients
                     .Where(i => i.CustomerId ==_userResolverService.GetCustomerId())
                     .Include(i => i.IngredientComposition)
                     .Select(i => _mapper.Map<Ingredient, IngredientDto>(i))
                     .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Add `CreateMap<IngredientComposition, Composition>();` and try again.

Comment: Hi unfortunately this doesn't work. I still get null instead of array on IngredientDto but Ingredient has attached collection - Look edit how I'm getting data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must do add `CreateMap<IngredientComposition, Composition>();` and after doing this you must do change your Linq Query. You can use [AutoMapper.EF6](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6)

```
return _context.Ingredients
                 .Where(i => i.CustomerId ==_userResolverService.GetCustomerId())
                 .Include(i => i.IngredientComposition)
                 .ProjectToList<IngredientDto>();
```

after use this you donot need use `Select`.

note: donot forget add `_mapper.ConfigurationProvider` in `ProjectToList`

```
ProjectToList<IngredientDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

if you don't set it to get this Exception:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with Appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

more [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961439/mapper-not-initialized-when-use-projectto).

**Update:** your properties must have the same name.if you change Dto property `Ingredients` to `IngredientComposition` don't need use `ForMember`.

Comment: Include is not needed, by default AM fetches everything.

Comment: Yes, maybe @sziszu do use eager loading.

Comment: Strange, it still returns null. Can this be caused because it's .net core? I also do not have ProjectToList, so I did it like that: return await _context.Ingredients.Where(i => i.CustomerId == _userResolverService.GetCustomerId())
        .ProjectTo<IngredientDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();

Answer (score 1):

Actually this worked for me:

Query:

```
return await _context.Ingredients.Where(i => i.CustomerId == _userResolverService.GetCustomerId())
        .Include(sx=>sx.IngredientComposition)
        .ProjectTo<IngredientDto>()
        .ToListAsync();
```

Maps:
First of All as you suggested, internal collection mapping then main objects mapping + ForMember which worked once internal objects were mapped

```
CreateMap<IngredientComposition, Composition>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>().ForMember(d => d.Ingredients, opt=>opt.MapFrom(c=>c.IngredientComposition)).ReverseMap();
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Oops, yes I think that your properties have same name.if you change Dto property `Ingredients` to   `IngredientComposition` don't need use `ForMember`.

Comment: Yeah @Soheil Alizadeh you're right, once changed it works as well, I'll amend answer to include this information

Comment: if my answer is correct to do Accept it thanks, @sziszu.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a map for the child DTO, Automapper is smart enough to figure it out without the `ForMember`:

```
CreateMap<IngredientComposition , Composition>()
    .ReverseMap();  //Reverse map tells AM to go both ways

CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>()
    .ReverseMap();

// CreateMap<IngredientDto, Ingredient>();  ** Not needed with ReverseMap()
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately this doesn't work. I still get null instead of array on IngredientDto but Ingredient has attached collection  - Look edit how I'm getting data